# Stop LAN IP changing wether connected to wifi or ethernet

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

Ive got an HP, W10 Pro laptop that i want to access via Microsoft Remote Desktop, to do this im accessing it by it LAN IP.

Because our router re user LAN IPs we have setup a MAC to IP binding for the HP laptops MAC address.

The only problem is that the Laptop seems to have 2 MAC addresses, which each get their own LAN IP assigned wether the laptop is using an ethernet or wifi connection.

Other than only sticking to one network interface, can we "bind the MAC addresses" or do something similar so that the router can always apply the same LAN IP ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you call binding the MAC to the IP-address is technically known as a static DHCP reservation.
Unfortunately you can only reserve any IP to just 1 MAC address, but you can make as many reservation as you like for the same computer.
So you make 2 reservations: One for the wired interface and one for the Wifi interface.
(If both interfaces are active simultaneously the laptop will prefer to use the faster of the 2 interfaces which usually will be the wired interface,)

So you just try the IP which is setup for the wired interface first. If that isn't reachable you try the IP for the Wifi interface.
One of them should work. If neither works the laptop is offline (or out of reach of the Wifi).

Answer (score 1):

> Ive got an HP, W10 Pro laptop that i want to access via Microsoft
>   Remote Desktop, to do this im accessing it by it LAN IP.

I'm going to assume by this you mean, you're working on a network and your access is not through the internet.

> The only problem is that the Laptop seems to have 2 MAC addresses,
>   which each get their own LAN IP assigned wether the laptop is using an
>   ethernet or wifi connection.

I should think you have two NIC's, one being a wireless interface with a MAC address, and another cabled interface with it's own seperate MAC address.

Your only problem here seems to be that you whenever you try to remotely control the laptop, you are effectively gambling as to whether or not the laptop is getting it's IP from the wireless card or the Wired card. Disconnecting either will force the laptop to receive it's address always by the same interface thus eliminating your issues.

1. On the laptop, press start, type "cmd" wait for the menu to populate and then press enter.
2. On the newly started command prompt type "ipconfig -all" and press enter, this will display your extended network settings. One of the fields is the MAC address.  This will show all interfaces so you should see at least two MAC addresses. One for the wired another for the wireless.
3. Compare with the MAC that you have a preference to connect to and take note from which interface that MAC belongs to.

Now armed with this knowledge you know which interface you should keep disconnected.